# Add image size to image generated by WP customizer?

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-images

I have a custom image field in my wp customizer and I can call it up in my template file like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( "my_img" ); ?>">
```

I want to add one of my image sizes (such as "thumbnail") to it like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( "my_img", 'thumbnail'); ?>">
```

This doesn't work though (don't know if that is even structured right :) ). **How might I accomplish this, or do I have to manually set the height and/or width in the functions code?**

Here's my settings/control in functions.php if you need it:

```
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'my_img', array());
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'my_img_control',
            array(
                'label'      => __( 'My Image', 'nowak' ),
                'section'    => 'my_img_section',
                'settings'   => 'my_img',
                'priority'   => 1
            )
        )
    );
```

Comment: yes you suppose to add this parameter in function array 'height'=>100, 
                'width'=>100, 
                'flex_width'=>true, 
                'flex_height'=>true,

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution to this?

Comment: @BeccaN I was not

Comment: I would very much like to see an answer too